# Script to automatically copy the next line of text from a text file each time I paste it somewhere

Tags: automation, autohotkey, copy-paste

I have a text file that contains some information on each line. I want to copy automatically the first line of the file, and then paste it somewhere else. As soon as I paste that line, I again want to automatically copy the 2nd line of the text file. And then I will paste it somewhere else and automatically copy the 3rd line of the text file and so on.

Is there any way to do this? Can I do this with Autohotkey for windows? if yes, please write me a script that can be used to do this. And if not, please tell me some other ways to do this...

Comment: Must it be on Windows ?  Please show what you have done so far.  If this is a once only affair, then it may be faster to just do manually.

Comment: 1. Yes, it must be on windows

2. The file will contain more than 10,000 lines, so doing it manually is not an option, unfortunately. 

3. I have asked chatGPT to write me a script, but it isn't working. When started the script, nothing is copied in the clipboard. Here is the code ChatGPT given to me:

https://chat.openai.com/share/0a2726e7-0e66-4bdf-95b6-b17cc79fdaf6

Comment: Even with AutoHotKey, this will take too long. Please explain better your problem with more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This AutoHotKey script copies the next line of a text file each time you press F1:

```
F1::
    Index++ ; checks the number in the variable "Index" and increases it by 1 each time you press F1
    FileReadLine, line, C:\My TextFile.txt, %Index%
    clipboard := line
    ; show the copied text for 3 seconds in the upper left corner of the active window: 
    ToolTip, Line%Index%`n%line%`ncopied, 0, 0
    Sleep, 3000
    ToolTip
return
```

And this pastes the next line of a text file each time you press F2:

```
F2::
    Index++ ; checks the number in the variable "Index" and increases it by 1 each time you press F2
    FileReadLine, line, C:\My TextFile.txt, %Index%
    SendInput, %line%
return
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you so much :D

A question: is there any way to show the copied text? Just to make sure what text is copied. This should not take the focus away from the window I am currently pasting in

Comment: I added a ToolTip to show the copied text.